# SQL- How to select the Student Name who is registered for all Modules?

Tags: mysql

Student

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| Sid  | sName | content                              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    |  Tim  | ...                                  |
| 2    | boyo  | ...                                  |
| 3    | Carl  | ...                                  |
| 4    | Life  | ...                                  |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Modules

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| mID  | mName | content                              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | Data  | ...                                  |
| 2    | IT    | ...                                  |
| 3    | Math  | ...                                  |
|      |       | ...                                  |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Registration

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| sID  | mID   | content                              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 1     | ...                                  |
| 1    | 2     | ...                                  |
| 1    | 3     | ...                                  |
| 3    | 1     | ...                                  |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: You will need to join the tables on sID and mID. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried a sql but it wasnt working but I going and do some changes to it now and see if it work

Comment: I got through with this sql it would have extra stuff since the post I posted was just a sample but here SELECT sName, address
FROM Student, Registration, Module
WHERE Student.studentID = Registration.studentID 
AND Module.moduleID = Registration.moduleID
GROUP BY sName, address 
HAVING COUNT (Registration.moduleID) = (SELECT count(moduleID) FROM Module)

Comment: I don't think Juergen answer works correctly if there are two students named 'Tim'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your data by the students and take only those having the same module count registered as there are modules in total

```
select s.sname
from students s
join Registration r on s.sid = r.sid
group by s.sname
having count(r.mid) = (select count(mid) from modules)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, grouping by SID and NAME :

```
CREATE TABLE STUD (SID INT, SNAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE MODU (MID INT, MNAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE REGI (SID INT, MID INT);
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES (1,'Tim');
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES (2,'Boyo');
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES (3,'Karl');
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES (4,'Life');
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES (5,'Tim');
INSERT INTO MODU VALUES (1,'Data');
INSERT INTO MODU VALUES (2,'IT');
INSERT INTO MODU VALUES (3,'Math');

INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (5,1);
INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (5,2);
INSERT INTO REGI VALUES (5,3);


SELECT A.SID, A.SNAME 
FROM STUD A
INNER JOIN REGI  B ON A.SID = B.SID
GROUP BY A.SID, A.SNAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS RC_MODULES FROM MODU)
;
```

Output:

```
    SID SNAME
1   1   Tim
2   5   Tim
```